# Failed building wheel for mysqlclient on macOS

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I have been troubleshooting this problem for the past 3 days, tried every method in stack and no luck, I am relatively new to Django and python so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
so I have been having a problem with installing mysqlclient through "pipenv install mysqlclient"
returning:   `ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient`

full summary:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing mysqlclient...
Resolving mysqlclient...
Installing...
⠸ Installing mysqlclient...[31m[1mError: [0m An error occurred while installing [32mmysqlclient[0m!
Error text: Collecting mysqlclient (from -r 
/var/folders/x4/6p57c76d173_b99bb3rtc2q40000gn/T/pipenv-rva1k23w-requirements/pipenv-xzl65j4d-requirement.txt (line 1))
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build mysqlclient

[36m  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      mysql_config --version
      ['8.0.33']
      mysql_config --libs
      ['-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib', '-lmysqlclient', '-lzlib', '-lzstd', '-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib', '-lssl', 
'-lcrypto', '-lresolv']
      mysql_config --cflags
      ['-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql']
      ext_options:
        library_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib', '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib']
        libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'zlib', 'resolv']
        extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
        extra_link_args: []
        include_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,1,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.1')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/constants
      warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
      
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g 
-Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.1 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql 
-I/Users/sonaallaibrahim/Desktop/storefront/my-test-env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c 
MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/_mysql.o 
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lmysqlclient -lzlib -lresolv -o 
build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-311-darwin.so
      ld: library not found for -lzlib
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
[0m
✘ Installation Failed
```

am using python 3.11
running on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 M1 chip

as I said any suggestions will help a lot

tried uninstalling and reinstalling wheel
tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql
tried unlinking mysql and link it back
tried brew mysql connector
tried brew mysql-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `zlib` is not found. It means either the library is not installed, or python is not able to find it. So the first thing to do is to install the library.

```
brew install zlib
```

Next, we need to set a couple of env variables for Python to look for the libraries in the right folder. Set the following env variables (or add them to your .bashrc)

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
```

The actual path for zlib might vary (its `/usr/local/opt/zlib` in this case. The path in your machine can be obtained by doing: `brew --prefix zlib`

Comment: this helped a lot thank you, it solved the problem with the "Zlib", although another problem come up, still unable to install mysqlclient, I will spend sometime trying solve it by my self, I will comeback if I couldn't , thank you very much for ur time